# cypress conditional testing skip to next line

Tags: conditional-statements, cypress

Hi there I'm new at cypress so I'm not sure if what I'm trying to write makes any sense.
With the below, I would like to remove the cookies notification by clicking on it, but in case the cookies notification is not visible, I would like to skip this step and move to the next one.

```
//cookies notification close button
        it('cookies notification', () => {
          const $body = cy.get("body")
          if ($body.find('[class="pg-layer cookie pg-layer-open state-app-home"]'))
          {
            cy.get('[class="fa-fw far fa-times fa-1-5x mxn material-icons"]').click()
            
           }
           
           else {shouldSkip}
           
          })
```

The above function is not working, could anyone help out please?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the find part of the code add condition to check the length of that element which you want to check as follows, that should do the trick. eg.

```
if (body.find('some element locator').length > 0){
clickSomething
}

//cookies notification close button
        it('cookies notification', () => {
          const $body = cy.get("body")
          if ($body.find('[class="pg-layer cookie pg-layer-open state-app-home"]').length > 0)
          {
            cy.get('[class="fa-fw far fa-times fa-1-5x mxn material-icons"]').click()
            
           }
           
           else {shouldSkip}
           
          })
```

Answer (score 0):

For conditional testing in Cypress, install the [cypress-if](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-if) package.

It's a major improvement over the officially documented way of doing what you want.

```js
cy.get('[class="pg-layer cookie pg-layer-open state-app-home"]')  
  .if()
  .within($cookieLayer => {
    cy.get('[class="fa-fw far fa-times fa-1-5x mxn material-icons"]')
      .click()
  })
```

Basically, having `.if()` in the chain stops the previous `cy.get()` command from failing when the element does not exist.

---

BTW you can probably find a better selector for the the Cookie accept button, and shorten the test code a bit.

Maybe:

```js
cy.get('[class="pg-layer cookie pg-layer-open state-app-home"]')  
  .if()
  .contains('button', 'Accept Cookies')
  .click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't work with return values as you are doing in the first line of your test.

Solution: just delete that const body declaration and open a closure this way:

```
    it('cookies notification', () => {
      cy.get("body").then($body => {
      if ($body.find('[class="pg-layer cookie pg-layer- 
    open state-app-home"]').length > 0)
      {
        cy.get('[class="fa-fw far fa-times fa-1-5x mxn 
    material-icons"]').click()
        
       }
       
       else {shouldSkip}
       
      })
    })
```

Please read this chapter https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases#Return-Values